# Client/Screen Coordinate Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, coordinates

I've fallen down a deep rabbit hole.  There are actually two issues that I've dealt with.  I don't think anyone will have a solution for the first issue (mentioned in the next paragraph), so I guess the real question is how the heck to use PointToScreen/PointToClient reliably.

I want to use balloons to show validation failures for a user control I've written.  The way to do this is to use a tooltip with IsBalloon set.  In my validation error handler, I call Show() on the tooltip with my user-control as the parameter.  This works if I click on another control, but not if I use tab to leave the control.  I've even tried hacks like queuing a task on another thread to sleep a bit, then try to show the balloon.  Nothing works.

So, I decided to try to go around this and use the main window ("this") as the parameter and specify coordinates, i.e.:

```
_balloon.Show(text, this, pos);
```

I can't seem to calculate the position (pos), though.

I'd like for the position to be the bottom right corner of the control, so here that is:

```
var clientBottomRight = new Point(_ctrlCallbackPhone.Width, _ctrlCallbackPhone.Height);
```

Then, I try to get the actual screen coordinates of that spot like so:

```
var screenPosition = _ctrlCallbackPhone.PointToScreen(clientBottomRight);
```

Finally, I try to get the coordinates on the main form ("this") like so:

```
var mainPosition = this.PointToClient(screenPosition);
```

Then I show the balloon.  You have to do it twice because of a Windows bug.

```
_balloon.Show(string.Empty, this, mainPosition);  
_balloon.Show(text, this, mainPosition);
```

The result is well above and slightly to the left of where it should be.  Although the margin of error looks like about the size of the title bar, I don't see how that's it.  I'm getting the screen coordinates of a spot, and asking for the client coordinates of that same spot.

Now, of course, if someone has a real solution to making the balloon work when I tab away from the control, I'd stop caring about the screen coordinates thing.  I imagine this is some sort of Windows weirdness, though, that I won't be able to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand why this works, but this results in the correct coordinates:

```
var mainPosition = this.PointToClient(screenPosition);
mainPosition = new Point(
               mainPosition.X + SystemInformation.VerticalResizeBorderThickness,
               mainPosition.Y + SystemInformation.CaptionHeight + SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness);
```